# Unable to track an entity because primary key is null

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, dbcontext

I have a `User` and an `Organization` model, and an `Organization` may have many users.

`Organization` model class:

```
public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
```

User model

```
[Key]
[ForeignKey("Organization")]
public int? OrganizationId { get; set; }
public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
```

In context

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(u => new {u.Id, u.OrganizationId});
 modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>().HasKey(o => new {o.Id});
```

When I want to insert one user with null organization, I get this error

> Unable to track an entity of type 'User' because primary key property 'OrganizationId' is null.

Comment: I think the problem is: you have defined a null-able int as your PK. Changing it to `int` and using `0` instead of `null` may solve your issue.

Comment: PKs cannot be null my friend

Comment: Why is the `OrganizationId` (FK to the Organization table) the **PK** of table `User`?? Doesn't really make any sense..... shouldn't you have a `UserID` as the PK for the `User` table, and `OrganizationId` would only be the FK to Organization?

Comment: Your code example suggests that `User` has a property named `Id` (which sounds like it would make a good primary key) but it is absent from your model. Did you leave out something by mistake? Please clarify which property is intended to be the primary key.

Comment: Modify OrganizationId int not int? , it's [key]

Comment: @marc_s PK's can be FK's as well, like here in a one-to-one relationship. That only part of the PK is the FK seems to point to a (dirty) join table, but that is another story.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to seperate your organization and userId  like this.

If I understand you correctly,

- one organisation has many users,
- one user may have one organisation

User model

```
[Key]
public int Id{ get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Organization")]
public int? OrganizationId { get; set; }
public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
```

In context (I am not sure, this may be wrong or should be optional, try this :) )

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>() // One organizatio
 .HasMany(c => c.User)        //has many users
 .WithOptional(c => c.Organization) //  but each user doesn't need a organization
 .HasForeignKey(c => c.OrganizationId) // users which have an organization, has a foreignId
 .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```